# How to use IBinder.DeathRecipient?

Tags: android

Can anyoane explain me how to use `linkToDeath()` because I've searched on Google but unfortunately I did not fully understand how to use it in order to get a callback when a process that hosts a service goes away?

Thanks!

Comment: You implement the IBinder.DeathRecipient interface and pass an instance to linkToDeath(). Then binderDied() will be called when the binder has died, like any other callback. What is exactly you don't understand?

Comment: Maybe this [blog post](https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/binders-death-recipients.html) is helpful